# How can I "reverse" this regular expression?

Tags: regex

In a piece of software where the teacher will be allowed to enter a regular expression intended to analyse the student's response to a question, I need to prevent the use of these 4 *un-escaped* characters:

```
. * ^ $
```

The following expression matches these *un-escaped* characters. How can I re-write it so that it does the reverse, i.e. so that it matches escaped characters but does not match unescaped ones?
Of course, I can do this programmatically but I would prefer to do this directly in that software's authoring mode, where I'm allowed to enter just one regular expression. Here's the expression:

```
/(?<!\\)[\.\^\$\*\+\{\}]/g
```

Available at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/upXOe5/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update to address the comments:

If you want to reject strings that contain an unescaped character and match everything else, you may use the following:

```
^(?!.*(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*[.^$*+{}]).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxuBKp/1)**.

---

#### Original answer:

You may use the following:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\[.^$*+{}]
```

This matches any of the characters inside the character class *only if* it's preceded by an odd number of backslash characters (i.e., a single backslash that is optionally preceded by other escaped ones).

Note: The `.^$*+{}` characters don't need to be escaped as long as they're inside a character class.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIqwca/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `(?<!\\)` - Not preceded by a backslash character.
- `(?:\\\\)*` - Zero or more pairs of backslash characters (i.e., an escaped backslash).
- `\\[.^$*+{}]` - An escaped character amongst `.^$*+{}`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. That regexp does answer my query up to a point but I was not clear enough in my request. Actually I would like an expression that would work as follows: string "he's 25" = match; string "it cost 25\$" = match; string "it cost 25$" = do NOT match. That is to say match any characters except unescaped meta characters in the list ".^$*+{}". I hope this is more clear, but not sure if it's possible to achieve with just one regexp.

Comment: @papiJo So, do you want to match all characters in "it cost 25$" except for `$` or do you want to reject the whole string? If it's the former, you may just append `|[^.^$*+{}]` to the pattern above. If it's the latter, you may use `^(?!.*(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*[.^$*+{}]).+$`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxuBKp/1).

Comment: `^(?!.*(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*[.^$*+{}]).+$` does exactly what I want. Thanks!